# blend-exchange: if .blend file name is too long, the three action buttons become partly unusable

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blend-exchange

this already happened to me a few times, but it happened again today, so I'm here to report. I used developer tools in firefox to understand what happens, and found  that this is probably due to extremely long .blend filename, which expands its div container so much that it (partly) covers the three blue action buttons below ("flag", "favorite", "download")

[image]

In the image above, the file I was downloading today (question is [Can't identify where this lip is in hiding in this model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80274/cant-identify-where-this-lip-is-in-hiding-in-this-model)).

As you see, all three buttons are partly covered (but normally you can't see where, in the image above the oversized div is visible just thanks to the firefox developer tools) and, if you click on their respective "uncovered" areas, their link works, but not on the "covered" areas.

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't seem to exactly reproduce this in Firefox

Comment: @gandalf3 That image was taken from FF 45.9.0 ESR (at work we use ESR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report :)

I've [submitted a fix](https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/pull/32), chances are it'll be live sooner rather than later.

EDIT: The submitted fix is now live.

Comment: I like your solution better, I will update the code to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I received an email about this last Friday, and it was fixed earlier today:

https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/commit/c83b20679e658be0a0037b9f79ce1326ed33abc2

Thanks for the report!

EDIT: gandalf3, true to form, had a better solution, the code has been updated to use it.

Comment: Hi thanks, now the long file name wraps, so it should be always usable, thanks. Which answer should I mark as an accepted answer? Your or gandalf3's?

Comment: gandalf3's since I ended up using his code.